# Google App Engine - which tools to edit datastore locally?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to ask if there is any tools for Google App Engine to edit datastore in localhost?
In the Application Console, I can edit data on appspot, but for localhost, which tools are available?
Please advice!

Comment: @David: pls tell me how u r editing the datastore through appspot??
I mean i wand to add data without localhost..

Comment: I use the [remote API](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html) if I need to directly modify the datastore for a one-off modification.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's a console on the development server too:

```
http://localhost:8000
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_The_Development_Console

[For old versions:

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
```

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#The_Development_Console
]

Comment: As long as you don't need to edit any TextProperty values.

Comment: For Java version is seems no possible to add or edit an entity in this way in localhost. At least these options don't appear in the interface as they do when the application is deployed to the production environment.

Comment: With my Go GAE SDK, console is started on http://localhost:8000

Comment: This has been changed, the console is now at http://localhost:8000/ -- see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_The_Development_Console

Comment: You can also click on the "SDK Console" button in the Python SDK to bring up the page.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on Java side, you should definitely try [AppWrench](http://appwrench.onpositive.com). It provides full support for all App Engine data types as well as provides much more pretty viewing, sorting and filtering. It runs locally for free so I am enjoying using it now.

Vieweing Entities:

[Viewing Entities http://appwrench.onpositive.com/static/images/productivity/viewer.jpg](http://appwrench.onpositive.com/static/images/productivity/viewer.jpg)

Edit dialog:

[alt text http://appwrench.onpositive.com/static/images/productivity/edit2.png](http://appwrench.onpositive.com/static/images/productivity/edit2.png)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the development console to view and edit your datastore, memcache, task queue and cron jobs at `/_ah/admin/` in your local development server.

Comment: As long as you don't need to edit any TextProperty values.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest GAE versions the datastore admin is part of the *development console* at `http://localhost:8000/`

More info:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_The_Development_Console